# Https issues for SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

Currently I try to developed application by using SharePoint that retrieve data from List

Now I try to developed for Login Function, The error display as Below

**The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.**

Here with my Source Code

```
HttpWebRequest endpointRequest =(HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://mvponduty.sharepoint.com/sites/devspace/_api/web/Lists");
            endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
            endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
            endpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization",
              "Bearer " + tokenkey.ToString());
            HttpWebResponse endpointResponse =(HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();

            lblResult.Text = endpointResponse.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply retrieve the lists using SharePoint Rest API, I suggest using HttpClient instead. It's the newest/modern API that supports asynchronous http requests.
Your HttpWebRequest may have involved some disposing issue but I can't prove.

Try this:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8");
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://<site url>/_api/web/lists");
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "your_token");
    try
    {
        var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // <= this will throw an exceception if status code is not within 200 - 209
        // Do whatever with the response object.
        // To get the response content:
        var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(content);
        // Or simply display the status code:
        // lblResult.Text = response.StatusCode;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblResult.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```